# PHP / Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, pagination

I have a piece of php code that creates nice looking pagination, however when the permalinks are set to default (page=?284) rather than something like post name (/post-name) the pagination buttons don't work and just keep loading the first page content.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;   
$total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
if($total > 1) {
if ( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') ){$current_page = 1;}
$perm_structure = get_option('permalink_structure');
$format = empty($perm_structure) ? '&page=%#%' : 'page/%#%/';
$paginate_return_data = paginate_links(array(
'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
'format' => $format,
'current' => $current_page,
'total' => $total,
'mid_size' => 4,
'type' => 'plain'
));
echo $paginate_return_data;
}
?>
```

Can you tell what is going wrong with this code to only allow for the post name style of permalinks to work?

Comment: Why would want the default? The other ones are called "pretty" permalinks for a reason, and, AFAIK, they are much better for SEO... Of course, this doesn't answer your question, just wondering...

Comment: Because all versions need to work.  I don't want something to be broken just because its not used as much.

Comment: I understand that, but you should choose one permalink format and try to stick to it till the end of times. This is not something you'll be changing every year. And, really, the default is not recommended. Anyway, hope someone can answer your Question.

Comment: I'm a web designer, this theme is not just for me.

Answer (score 0):

This might help
I had a look at the paginate_links function 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

It has that the default for the total parameter is 1.
However if I pass 1 to the function it returns null.

In the example below I passed 2 and the var_dump shows that 2 links  are returned. So maybe you need to add a check to see if $total is 2 or more.

```
$paginate_return_data = paginate_links( array(
// 'base' => '%_%',
'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
'format' => $format ,
'current' => $current_page,
// 'total' => $total,
'total' => 2
 ) );

var_dump($paginate_return_data);
```